# replace fragment very slow

Tags: android, fragmentmanager

I found that it is very slow when I replace a fragment.

Is there any event to get the commit status that I want to know it is finish commit.

Here is my code.. I want to disable my processbar when it changed.

```
@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View drawerView) {

    if (mFragmentToSet != null) {
        ((ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.flContent, mFragmentToSet).commit();
((ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mFragmentToSet = null;}
```

Comment: I never felt that replacing fragment is slow, it can be cause you do lot of things in your UI thread in onCreateView or onCreate of Fragment. Can you add your fragment that is being slow to load?

Comment: In my case...after DrawerClosed .. fragment still need 1-2 sec for closing and replace a new one

Comment: Why do you set fragment on onDrawerClosed? why dont you use onNavigationDrawerItemSelected callback for this? If you need to change your fragment on click of item of drawer, you can use this method onNavigationDrawerItemSelected. If you need explanation, tell me i'll post an answer.

Comment: it is because if I replace on onNavigationDrawerItemSelected.. it will freeze until fragment changed..

Comment: I found the ans... is setVisibility when the other view is created.

Comment: You could use `runOnCommit()'  method. You can then add a Runnable to this transaction that will be run after this transaction has been committed.